# How do I use protobuf on a Mac with Python?

Tags: python, macos, protocol-buffers

1. I installed the package and ran all of the correct commands. I did this for 2.6.1, 2.7, and 3.2. Between each I subsequently uninstalled the previous version. Within each version I went into the python folder and ran the python installation commands.
2. I ran `brew install protobuf` (and subsequently uninstalled it).
3. I ran `sudo pip install protobuf` (and subsequently uninstalled it).

The issue I am constantly getting is that the generated .py protobuf file calls imports from google.protobuf, but I am returned an error: `ImportError: No module named google.protobuf`

I then copy in the google folder (which you shouldn't have to do) and it stops returning that error, but the file and examples won't work.

Comment: Why are you installing and uninstalling all this?

Comment: Because of the ImportError. Searches for solutions (and previous SO post) didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was/am using PyCharm. The protobuf library doesn't automatically get linked to the PyCharm interpreter. If you run `python script.py` from the command line, there are no issues with missing modules.